# How to create a Trigger for creating the columns in a table on the insertion of data in another table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am having a table MstAttributes another as TrnIndexAttributes. I want to create those many columns in TrnIndexAttributes table as many rows are there in MstAttributes. Means after insertion of a value in MstAttributesone column should be created in TrnIndexAttribute table like ID1,ID2,ID3....

Comment: Don't do that. Just... don't.

Comment: Adding columns dynamically is usually a bad idea because (for example) you have no way to manage the schema (limit table growth, manage indexes) and you can't write code to use the new columns because you don't know when they were added or what they contain. If you explain *why* you want to do this, someone may have an alternative solution.

Comment: And what are you going to do when you reach the record size limit? (hint, you will and prabaly fairly quickly)) How are you going to determine the correct datatype? Why on earth would you want to do this? If you don't know what columns you need at design time, perhaps a relational database is not the best tool for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you really feel like doing that (despite the rightful warning of Philip Kelley), you'll have to use dynamic query.

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCJAR(MAX) = N'ALTER TABLE TableOfInfiniteDoom ADD COLUMN' + [your logic for a name] + [your ligic for a type]
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

In your trugger (don't fortget the loop if you handle multyrows DML).